# Share Wi-Fi Internet access via Bluetooth on Raspberry Pi

Tags: raspbian, networking, wireless, bluetooth

I have tried multiple ways I got on Google, without luck.

I know if I am on an Ubuntu machine, I can use BlueMan to configure this. Actually I have already succeeded in that. However, I think BlueMan based approaches will NOT work because my Pi does NOT have X, and I don't want to install BlueMan either. I would like to solve this just using BlueZ and some simple scripts if necessary.

My Raspberry Pi runs Raspbian. My BlueZ is version 4.99. `hcid.conf` is NOT found in `/etc/bluetooth`. `pand` has been installed but I cannot see any new interface related to Bluetooth added to `ifconfig` results.

My idea is that, I should be able to create a virtual interface into `ifconfig` results, and manage it with a static IP address defined in `/etc/network/interfaces`. Then I can run normal IP forwarding etc. I am not sure if this is the correct way of doing this, but so far I cannot find anything new in results of `ifconfig`.

A lot of articles I found use bridge. I'd prefer NAT if possible. Because I don't think bridges work for Wi-Fi interfaces. I already have a Wi-Fi to Wi-Fi forwarding NAT configured on this Pi, therefore, once I can connect a device to a virtual interface on Pi, the rest should be trivial, I think.

---

I have asked this question on Super User, but they suggested I ask it here.

Comment: Have a look at this --> http://www.hkepc.com/forum/viewthread.php?tid=1710030 and this -->  https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=36&t=57529

Comment: @dastaan Have you read my question carefully? Your link uses eth0 which is Ethernet, and it uses bridging. I need to work with Wi-Fi, and bridging will not work, so I need an NAT solution.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?